# OpenFeint Achievement and Leaderboards buttons not displayed (always)

Tags: ios, openfeint, achievements, leaderboard

I've added a bunch of achievements and a leader board on the openfeint developer dashboard then I downloaded the offline configuration file and I also added a test user.
When I open the application dashboard nor the Achievements neither the Leaderboard button appear.

I noticed that in the configuration file I had false and false. I set them to true and uninstalled the app. When I reinstalled it everything worked fine, but the as soon as i pressed the home button and then reload the app, the buttons disappeared.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a server side issue. Now it's fixed.